# set environment variable by condition in installshield

Tags: installshield

In my project, I use installshield to insert an environment variable during installation.

```
PEAK_LIMIT = 1000
```

However, if I change the value to say - 1500, then during re-installation with higher versions causes the value to be reset to 1000. Is there a way to preserve the current value 1500 instead of resetting?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a hard coded value in your Environment table.  Substitute it out with a property that equals that value.  Then use a custom action during the install to assign the current value to the property if it has a value.  This way when MSI rewrites the environment variable it'll keep the value it read.

Another approach would be to create a second environment variable (PEAK_LIMIT_OVERRIDE) that has higher priority in your application.  This way the installer can set the default value to what it thinks is correct and keep that apart from user controlled data.